# How to unmarshall json lists using Spring Boot RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have to parse a REST response in json and it has a lot of nested lists with many objects.

The response contains an item called "ObjectList" which has a list and inside, two elements, "ObjectA" and "ObjectB". I don't know how to parse the response to objects using Jackson annotations.

The json looks like this:

```
    "ObjectList": [
            {
                "ObjectA": {
                    "property1": false,
                    "property2": true
            },
                "ObjectB": {
                    "property1": 66,
                    "property2": true
            },
            {
                "ObjectA": {
                    "property1": false,
                    "property2": true
            },
                "ObjectB": {
                    "property1": 66,
                    "property2": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My code looks like this

```
    ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response.class);
    Response response = response.getBody();
```

Response is:

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class TimesheetListResponse {

        @JsonProperty("ObjectA")
        private List<ObjectA> objectAList;

        @JsonProperty("ObjectB")
        private List<ObjectB> objectBList;
```

That does not work at all, and I'm confused about how to map this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement the model structure may look like below. Within the objectList map in Response object, you need to add HashMap with keys  as "ObjectA"/"ObjectB" string and value as instance of ObjectA/ObjectB. I have taken value type of Map as Object, so that any object type A/B can fit in there. Add corresponding @JsonXXX annotations.

```
public class Response {

private List<Map<String,Object>> objectList;

//Getters & Setters
}

public class ObjectB {

String propB1;

String propB2;
}


public class ObjectA {

String propA;

String propA1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would consider the entry in the list as another wrapper object that can either ObjectA or ObjectB. I.e.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Parent {

    @JsonProperty("ObjectList")
    private List<ChildWrapper> objectList = new ArrayList<>(); 
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class ChildWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("ObjectA")
    private Child ObjectA;

    @JsonProperty("ObjectB")
    private Child ObjectB;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Child {

    @JsonProperty("property1")
    private int property1;

    @JsonProperty("property2")
    private boolean property2;
}
```

Comment: Remember, there could be multiple elements of ObjectA/ObjectB under the list. In above example, only one instance each is possible.

Comment: The `ChildWrapper` would handle that. Consider these two items in the list:

 Object1: `{
      "ObjectA": { .. }
    }`

 Object2: `{
      "ObjectB": { .. }
    }`

Both can be represented by the `ChildWrapper`. This is only assuming that the response could be either `ObjectA` or `ObjectB` though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the mapping was fine, I only had to initialize the Arraylist. The main issue was that the endpoint was returning empty because of a parameter that I forgot.